# Applying Extended Euclidean Algorithm for Galois Field to Find Multiplicative Inverse

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

I was trying to apply the Extended Euclidean Algorithm
for Galois Field. Among the many resources available,
I found the methodology outlined in [this document](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/number-theory/exteuc/exteuc.pdf) easy to grasp.

The above works fine when applied to numbers.

Now, for $\textit{GF}(2^3)$, if I take the polynomial $x^2$ and
the irreducible polynomial $P(x) = x^3 + x + 1$, I can form the table 
below,

\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Remainder}\ (a)   &        \text{Quotient}\ (q)  &       y\\\hline
x^3 + x + 1 &&                         x^2 + 1\\
x^2& x& x\\
x + 1 &x &1\\
1& x + 1& 0
\end{array}

So, $(x^2)^{-1} \bmod P(x) $ comes out to be $x^2 + 1$. Whereas from other literature I find that the actual result should be, $x^2 + x + 1$.

What is wrong with the calculation I have done?

Comment: I don't understand the table. What does $y$ mean? Why isn't there any quotient in the first row? If the first thing you do is divide $x^3+x+1$ by $x^2$, shouldn't you get quotient $x$ and remainder $x+1$?

Comment: Please see page 3 of the resource I have mentioned. You start with only $x^3+x+1$ and $x^2$ in the first column, divide $x^3+x+1$ by $x^2$, put the quotient in the second column and remainder in the first column. You divide the last two entries in the first column and repeat the process. $y$ is defined in page 2 of the document.

Comment: Got it. But when you divide $x^2$ by $x+1$, the quotient is $x+1$.

Comment: What is wrong with taking the quotient $x$ and remainder $x$?

Comment: Well, you didn't do that, either --- you have quotient $x$, and remainder $1$, which is just wrong. But quotient $x$ and remainder $x$ violates the condition, degree of remainder strictly less than degree of divisor.

Comment: Oh, goodness! Trying to cram so many things in a few months and sometimes missing the basic.

Comment: You can write up and post an answer to your own question. After some time, you can accept the answer. This keeps the Unanswered list uncluttered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To calculate the table you have provided, you start with the two given polynomials in the first column, the one with higher order at the top. In this case, $P(x) = x^3 + x + 1$ goes in the first row.

So, for the case you have provided, the table looks like,

\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Remainder}\ (a)   &        \text{Quotient}\ (q)  &       y\\\hline
x^3 + x + 1 &&                     \\
x^2& & \\
\end{array}

As indicated in the [document provided](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/number-theory/exteuc/exteuc.pdf), the $a$ and $q$ columns are filled in using the Euclidean algorithm, i.e. by successive division: divide
the next-to-the-last $a$ by the last $a$. The quotient goes into the $q$-column, and the remainder goes into the
$a$-column.

After the $a$ and $q$ columns are filled up, the table will look like,

\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Remainder}\ (a)   &        \text{Quotient}\ (q)  &       y\\\hline
x^3 + x + 1&&\\ 
x^2& x&\\
x + 1& x + 1&\\
1& x + 1
\end{array}

You should remember that all mathematical operations are done over 
$\textit{GF}(2^3)$.

Your mistake was that when you divide $x^2$ by $x+1$, the quotient is $x+1$ and the remainder is $1$. It will be incorrect to take the quotient as $x$ and remainder as $x$. When carrying out a [polynomial division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division_of_polynomials#Euclidean_division), you should remember that: given two [univariate polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnivariatePolynomial.html) $a$ and $b \not= 0$ defined over a [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29), there exist two polynomials $q$ (the quotient) and $r$ (the remainder) which satisfy,

$a=bq+r$

and

$\deg(r)<\deg(b)$,
where $\deg(...)$ denotes the degree. Moreover $q$ and $r$ are uniquely defined by these relations.

Quotient $x$ and remainder $x$ violates the condition, degree of remainder is strictly less than degree of divisor.

Anyway, coming back to your original problem, the only task remains is to fill up the $y$ column. The $y$-column is filled in from bottom to top. Always start with $0$ for the last $y$ and $1$ for the next-to-
the-last $y$.

Then, working from bottom to top, fill in the $y$’s using the rule,
$(\text{next}\ y) = (\text{last}\ q) \times (\text{last}\ y) + (\text{next-to-last}\ y)$.

So, with the $y$'s filled up, the table becomes,

\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Remainder}\ (a)   &        \text{Quotient}\ (q)  &       y\\\hline
x^3 + x + 1&& x^2 + x + 1\\ 
x^2& x&x + 1\\
x + 1& x + 1&1\\
1& x + 1&0
\end{array}

Again, you should remember that all mathematical operations are done over 
$\textit{GF}(2^3)$.

So, your  inverse of $x^2$ is now given as the topmost $y$ value
that was computed, $x^2 + x + 1$.

Indeed, to  check that $x^2 + x + 1$ is in fact the inverse of $x^2$, where we use the properties
that $x^3 \equiv x + 1 \bmod P(x)$ and $x^4 \equiv x^2 + x \bmod P(x)$:

\begin{align}
(x^2 + x + 1) \cdot x^2 &=& x^4 + x^3 + x^2\\
&\equiv& (x^2 + x) + (x + 1) + x^2 \bmod P(x)\\
&\equiv& 1 \bmod P(x)
\end{align}

Comment: Are you talking to yourself?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, how else do I answer the question? Or do you suggest editing the answer is some manner? Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: No, it's fine. It strikes me as funny that you address yourself as "you", but it's fine.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Actually, I wanted to make the answer useful to other people, not only to me. I already got the answer. That made me write the answer in that manner.

Comment: Good explanation sir, I was looking for the same thing (your student)

Comment: This explanation is really fine...it is kind of "unscientific" but extremely understandable!