# Can I select the $i$th member of a pseudo-random permutation of $n$ integers in $O(1)$ steps?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations, computational-complexity, integers

This is in the context of computer programming where a $b$-byte integer is $0\leq i < 2^{8b}-1$.

I have a list of objects indexed by $i=0,1,2,...$ and I want to assign to each object another unique integer $P(i)$ in the same range $0\leq P(i) < 2^{8b}-1$. That is to say, $P(i)$ selects from some permutation of the integers.

One algorithm to do this would be to create an array $a[0]=0, a[1]=1, ...$, randomly shuffle (permute) the elements of that array, and then define $P(i)=a[i]$ which is a constant-time lookup, but requires a prohibitive amount of storage as well as an up-front computational cost.

Is there an alternative way to calculate, without using storage, an alternative $P(i)$ in constant time? The particular values are not at all important. The three key requirements are:

- $P(i)=P(j) \iff i=j$
- The values of $P(i)$ appear to be statistically random when written in sequence, I don't have a precise definition, just "they look random" or "the $P(i)$ should be evenly-distributed, $|i-P(i)|$ is equally likely to be small as to be large, for all $i$". It doesn't have to be cryptographically strong or anything like that, I'm just trying to maximise the Hamming distance between successive values in an "unpredictable" way.
- $P(i)$ to be computed in constant time and using constant storage with no inputs other than $i$ (e.g. no lookup tables).

Preferably, the algorithm would not require the use of any intermediate values outside the $2^{8b}$ range, but that's okay if necessary. Also, ideally the permutation would be keyed by some parameter $k$ giving $P_k(i)$.

The full range of $2^{8b}$ values does *not* have to be covered. It's fine to restrict $0\leq i<n$ for chosen, sufficiently large $n<2^{8b}$, and it's fine if $n<P(i)$ for some $i$.

How might I compute $P(i)$?

Comment: This should solve a lot of your issues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code

Comment: That seems to be a method of classifying/labelling permutations. My question is given a suitable (random-seeming) permutation, how can the $ith$ element of it be selected in constant time? I don't see how Lehmer codes help here.

Comment: In the obvious way: if you are able to generate a random number between $1$ and $n!$ efficiently, you are also able to generate a random permutation efficiently.

Comment: The $P$ function needs to be deterministic. Also this isn't really a hash function since it's invertible.

Comment: An inversion over a finite field gives a deterministic and invertible function. I already suggested that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{F}_{2^{8b}}=\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(q(x))$ where $q(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$with degree $8b$.
This field has $2^{8b}$ elements, hence every integer in the range $[0,2^{8b}-2]$ can be associated in a bijective way with an invertible element of this field, and the inversion in $\mathbb{K}^*$ meets the wanted constraints. To compute the inverse in a finite field has the same complexity as the extended euclidean algorithm, so it just depends (polynomially) on $b$, that is fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I could use a bit more help understanding this. What does the notation $\mathbb{F}_{2^{8b}}=\mathbb{F}_2/(q(x))$ mean? Is $q$ an arbitrary polynomial? And I thought computing the inverses of polynomials of high degree was only possible through numerical methods, so I guess you're referring to some procedure I'm not aware of. Can you please clarify your answer? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @spraff: polynomials here are just elements of a finite group, in particular a [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field). An example: in $\mathbb{F}_5$, the inverse of $2$ is $3$. Another example: in $\mathbb{F}_9=\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^2+1)$, the inverse of $x+1$ is $x+2$, since $$(x+1)\cdot(x+2) \equiv x^2+3x+2 \equiv 1.$$ We are working $\pmod{3}$ and $\pmod{x^2+1}$.

Comment: The inverse of an element of $\mathbb{F}_q^*$ (with $p$ being a prime or a power of some prime) can be computed through the extended euclidean algorithm, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445732/applying-extended-euclidean-algorithm-for-galois-field-to-find-multiplicative-in